# React native icons in Bottom Tab Navigation resulting in WARN The "EXNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules;

Tags: android, reactjs

I've tried following a number of different tutorials for creating Bottom Tab Navigation in React native, all of them resulting in the same error message. Perhaps the simplest one is the following totorial:
https://medium.com/@nutanbhogendrasharma/create-bottom-tab-navigation-in-native-mobile-app-part-3-9552820f6703

Bellow is the code in question:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

...

const HomeStack = () => {
    return (
        <View><Text>A</Text></View>
    )
};
HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home'
};

const WorkoutStack = () => {
    return (
        <View><Text>b</Text></View>
    )
};
WorkoutStack.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Workout'
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

 
function App() {
  return (

    <NavigationContainer>
       <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home';
              color = focused ? 'tomato' : 'grey';
              size = focused ? 25 : 20;
            } else if (route.name === 'workout') {
              iconName = focused ? 'workout' : 'workout';
              color = focused ? 'tomato' : 'grey';
              size = focused ? 25 : 20;
            }

            return <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          }
        })}
      >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Workout" component={WorkoutStack} />
        
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

Building for Android on Linux (on an Android simulator) I get the following error

```
 WARN  The "EXNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that expo-modules-core's native code is linked properly 
    at TabBarIcon (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&lazy=true&minify=false&app=com.plates&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:169264:17)
...
```

Additionally the icons don't show up. If I remove the `<MaterialCommunityIcons>` component, the error goes away and the navigation works fine, albeit without any icons obviously.

I've tried similar tutorials with `Ionicons` and they've resulted in similar error messages.

I've tried removing the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again. This does not fix the issue. See below for relevant entries in `package.json`

```
 16     "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
 17     "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
 18     "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
 19     "asset": "^0.4.13",
 20     "expo": "^49.0.22",
 21     "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
 22     "expo-modules-core": "^1.11.7",
 23     "expo-vector-icons": "^10.0.1",
```